# Cannot find Function Definition of an Event Observer class in Magento

Tags: php, function, magento, magic-methods

For anybody who has seen / used Magento, can you please tell me where can I find the following 3 function's definitions of the Catalog Product's save action's Event Observer class:-

1. `setBundleOptionsData()`
2. `setBundleSelectionsData()`
3. `setCanSaveBundleSelections()`

Please pardon me, for asking such a silly question, but I am really helpless.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

The worst part is that these above 3 methods are being used for the product object in a nice way, & they are working too. But where are their definitions?

**EDIT:-**
Okay, I can understand that these are used by the "Varien_Object", and these are simple setter functions using the concept of Magic Methods. But can somebody please tell what is the coding flow, when the program counter arrives at such a function, in this case in the Event Observer class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have run a search on all the files and can't find the definition then these are most likely using PHP's [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). Is this class inheriting (directly or indirectly) from Varien_Object? If so, then these are simple setter functions storing data in an array within the object.

To get these values back all you need to do is change the 'set' to 'get':

```
$this->setBundleOptionsData('whatever');
echo $this->getBundleOptionsData(); //Returns 'whatever'
```

If you're interested in how this works, look inside class Varien_Object. I've also described the mechanism [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407807/object-oriented-php-best-practices/2408805#2408805).

Comment: Thanks for such an info. But I have some more queries. This class is inherited indirectly from Varien_Object.

Comment: I really must admit your answer as wow. But if possible, please tell whether the point, which you mentioned, is really taking place or not.

Comment: You'll also want to give var_dump($this->getData()) a try, or $this->getData('bundle_options_data')