# PHP Object, set multiple properties

Tags: php, oop, object

Is it possible to set multiple properties at a time for an object in php?
Instead of doing:

```
$object->prop1 = $something;
$object->prop2 = $otherthing;
$object->prop3 = $morethings;
```

do something like:

```
$object = (object) array(
    'prop1' => $something,
    'prop2' => $otherthing,
    'prop3' => $morethings
);
```

but **without overwriting the object**.

Comment: Why would you want to obfuscate what the code is doing in this way? At some point in the future someone (**maybe you**) will need to read this code and doing something like this will only make it more difficult to understand.

Comment: Why not just paste this into a php file and run it? Instead of asking here if it would work, just try it yourself.

Comment: Just create a helper function to do it for you. Pass in the object and array.

Comment: It looks awful and it's more code, why would you need that?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53266

Comment: I was receiving an array wich values needed to be asigned as properties of my object, and yes the object has funtcions and other properties that need to be preserved. I just thought there was a 'magic' way to do so. Sure I can do it manually, I was just wondering ..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not like the way you want. but this can be done by using a loop.

```
$map =  array(
    'prop1' => $something,
    'prop2' => $otherthing,
    'prop3' => $morethings
);

foreach($map as $k => $v)
    $object->$k = $v;
```

See only 2 extra lines.

Comment: It's not 2 more lines, but **50% more lines**; worse if there are only two properties to set. Actually it's 3 lines if we don't cheat and use the bug-preventors `{` and `}`.

Comment: @Pacerier I hope you're trolling. In a real use-case such arrays could hold hundreds of values. Of course if you hand only 2 values, it's extra work because it's three lines. But if you work with an array with 358 values, this solution stays at three lines.

Comment: @Holonaut, It's meant to be a serious comment not a troll comment. Sure, there are bound to be use cases where there are hundreds of values, but many use cases have just two, three, or four values.

Comment: @Pacerier You can't be the judge of which use case occurs more frequently. OP's question was about setting multiple properties and the answer was valid. The fact that his example array had 3 values is simply incidental and should be treated as anything ranging from 2 to *. The answer was correct in achieving this and you're just not seeing the big picture.

Answer (score 12):

You should look at [Object Oriented PHP Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407807/object-oriented-php-best-practices/2408805#2408805) :

"since the setter functions return $this you can chain them like so:"

```
 $object->setName('Bob')
        ->setHairColor('green')
        ->setAddress('someplace');
```

This incidentally is known as a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: This is a completely different thing. He is talking about shortcuts for creating **variable properties** and that has nothing to do with your answer.

Comment: If you had been talking about using `public function __set($k, $v){ $this->$k=$v; return $this;}`, then it *still* wouldn't work because `(($obj->k="v")->k2)="v2";` is syntax error.

Comment: Why does this have 8 upvotes? It has nothing to do with the question that was asked... 

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you **don't** do it. Seriously, **don't**.

Your code is much MUCH cleaner the first way, it's clearer of your intentions, and you aren't obfocusing your code to the extent where sometime in the future someone would look at your code and think "What the hell was the idiot thinking"?

If you insist on doing something which is clearly the wrong way to go, you can always create an array, iterate it and set all the properties in a loop. I won't give you code though. It's evil.

Comment: Not true. Other languages have this syntax and they are hailed as **clean code**. It depends on **how** you use it.

Answer (score 3):

You could write some setters for the object that return the object:

```
public function setSomething($something)
{
 $this->something = $something;
 return $this; //this will return the current object
}
```

You could then do:

```
$object->setSomething("something")
       ->setSomethingelse("somethingelse")
       ->setMoreThings("some more things");
```

You would need to write a setter for each property as a `__set` function is not capable of returning a value.

Alternatively, set a single function to accept an array of property => values and set everything?

```
public function setProperties($array)
{
  foreach($array as $property => $value)
  {
    $this->{$property} = $value;
  }
  return $this;
}
```

and pass in the array:

```
$object->setProperties(array('something' => 'someText', 'somethingElse' => 'more text', 'moreThings'=>'a lot more text'));
```

Comment: "need to write a setter for each property as a __set function is not capable of returning a value". See my answer for a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question but for the benefit of others that come across it, I solved this myself recently and wanted to share the result

```
<?php
    //Just some setup
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $account = (object) array(
        'email' => 'foo',
        'dob'=>((object)array(
            'day'=>1,
            'month'=>1,
            'year'=>((object)array('century'=>1900,'decade'=>0))
        ))
    );
    var_dump($account);
    echo "\n\n==============\n\n";

    //The functions
    function &getObjRef(&$obj,$prop) {
        return $obj->{$prop};
    }

    function updateObjFromArray(&$obj,$array){
        foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
            if(!is_array($value))
                $obj->{$key} = $value;
            else{
                $ref = getObjRef($obj,$key);
                updateObjFromArray($ref,$value);
            }
        }
    }

    //Test
    updateObjFromArray($account,array(
        'id' => '123',
        'email' => 'user@domain.com',
        'dob'=>array(
            'day'=>19,
            'month'=>11,
            'year'=>array('century'=>1900,'decade'=>80)
        )
    ));
    var_dump($account);
```

Obviously there are no safeguards built in. The main caveat is that the `updateObjFromArray` function assumes that for any nested arrays within `$array`, the corresponding key in `$obj` already exists and is an object, this must be true or treating it like an object will throw an error.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't actually do this....but for fun I would

```
$object = (object) ($props + (array) $object);
```

you end up with an stdClass composed of $objects public properties, so it loses its type.

Comment: This overrides the object which fails to meet the requirement of the question. `$object === $old_object` is no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

Method `objectThis()` to transtypage class array properties or array to stdClass. Using direct transtypage (object) would remove numeric index, but using this method it will keep the numeric index.

```
public function objectThis($array = null) {
    if (!$array) {
        foreach ($this as $property_name => $property_values) {
            if (is_array($property_values) && !empty($property_values)) {
                $this->{$property_name} = $this->objectThis($property_values);
            } else if (is_array($property_values) && empty($property_values)) {
                $this->{$property_name} = new stdClass();
            }
        }
    } else {
        $object = new stdClass();
        foreach ($array as $index => $values) {
            if (is_array($values) && empty($values)) {
                $object->{$index} = new stdClass();
            } else if (is_array($values)) {
                $object->{$index} = $this->objectThis($values);
            } else if (is_object($values)) {
                $object->{$index} = $this->objectThis($values);
            } else {
                $object->{$index} = $values;
            }
        }
        return $object;
    }
}
```

Comment: the explanation preceding the code sample could use some improvement

Comment: What on Earth is a transtypage?