# Refactoring PHP file to remove code duplication

Tags: php, design-patterns, refactoring

I have a class that imports some users, transforms the users information and then inserts it into a database. I have on file `ImportEmployees` that has a method which calls 2 other classes to import data. One class gets some users matching certain criteria and the other class handles the remaining users. These two classes do exactly the same thing except for one method. That one method is what extracts the users data correctly so there are 2 additional, different classes that it will call. What is a good design pattern that handles this well, or a better way to handle this to remove code duplication.

Here is the entry point class `ImportEmployees`: [full class here](https://gist.github.com/dericcain/0b544185e6a223147f57e905c619e704)

```
public function handle()
{
    handle(new ImportNapaUsers($this->file));
    handle(new ImportNonNapaUsers($this->file));
}
```

And the `ImportNapaUsers` class: [full class here](https://gist.github.com/dericcain/c101509091340d5f7dda6a7d7d1ef873)

```
private function extractUsers()
{
    $users = new ExtractNapaUsers($this->users);
    $this->napaUsers = $users->getUsers();
}
```

And the `ImportNonNapaUsers` class: [full class here](https://gist.github.com/dericcain/7e1135232f13ebf041ead9b3b5ed1607)

```
private function extractUsers()
{
    $users = new ExtractNonNapaUsers($this->users);
    $this->napaUsers = $users->getUsers();
}
```

`$this->users` is the exact same in both of these. Also, both classes are identical except for the `extractUsers` method.

Comment: `identical` nope `new ExtractNapaUsers` is not `new ExtractNonNapaUsers` methods are not the same. Is that your code on git? And if not: Why do you want to change this?

Comment: Ignore my first comment. `good design pattern` dependency injection is the first to look for. Your `handle()` method is really against good oop. prevent to use `new` in a class method

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I would love for you to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not overcomplicate this with design patterns. What you need is inheritance and abstract classes.

Create an abstract class `ImportSomeUsers` with an abstract method extractUsers() like this

```
abstract class ImportSomeUsers {
    ...
    abstract protected function extractUsers();
}
```

Then define your classes by extending the `ImportSomeUsers` class:

```
class ImportNapaUsers extends ImportSomeUsers {

    protected function extractUsers() {
        $users = new ExtractNapaUsers($this->users);
        $this->napaUsers = $users->getUsers();
    }
}

class ImportNonNapaUsers extends ImportSomeUsers {

    protected function extractUsers() {
        $users = new ExtractNonNapaUsers($this->users);
        $this->napaUsers = $users->getUsers();
    }
}
```

Comment: @dericcain Thats your solution here!

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions That definitely cuts down on duplication. I really appreciate your thoughts on DI. That is something that I didn't think about.

Answer (score 1):

I try to elaborate this:

```
 public function handle()
 {
   handle(new ImportNapaUsers($this->file));
   handle(new ImportNonNapaUsers($this->file));
 }
```

- You have an class method that itself calls an global function, fully aginst oop
- Then you staticly call this function with fixed use of `new XYZ`, also against oop
- Then your public handle() has no return value, how do you note if something goes wrong?
- Also your handle() function seems to returning nothing

And:

```
private function extractUsers()
{
   $users = new ExtractNonNapaUsers($this->users);
   $this->napaUsers = $users->getUsers();
}
```

- since the method is `private` this would be better:

  `$this->extractUsers(new ExtractNonNapaUsers($this->users));`

And the method becomes

```
private function extractUsers($users)
{
   $this->napaUsers = $users->getUsers();
}
```

It is a very complex topic, you should read more about it:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection

[Object Oriented PHP Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407807/object-oriented-php-best-practices)

:)

Answer (score 0):

You also may use traits, something like:

```
namespace Traits;
trait UserExtractor
{
    private function extractUsers()
        {
            $users = new ExtractNapaUsers($this->users);
            $this->napaUsers = $users->getUsers();
        }
}
```

then ImportNapaUsers and ImportNonNapaUsers could use same method like:

```
use Traits\UserExtractor;

class ImportNapaUsers // (class ImportNonNapaUsers)
{
    use UserExtractor;
    //...
}
```